# Current location draggable marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

How can i let the "address"  locate a current location marker for the user on google map by clicking on the button rather than take the input value

http://jsfiddle.net/razanrab/WppF6/253/

```
<body>
  <div id="panel">
      <input id="city_country" type="textbox" value="Berlin, Germany">
      <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">
  </div>  
  <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
  <div id="infoPanel">
    <b>Marker status:</b>
    <div id="markerStatus"><i>Click and drag the marker.</i></div>
    <b>Current position:</b>
    <div id="info"></div>
    <b>Closest matching address:</b>
    <div id="address"></div>
  </div>
</body>


//js 

var geocoder;
var map;
var marker;

codeAddress = function () {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  var address = document.getElementById('city_country').value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
    zoom: 16,
            streetViewControl: false,
          mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
              mapTypeIds:[google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP] 
    },
    center: results[0].geometry.location,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.
```

Comment: if it is a mobile application then you can do it easily, `sensor` will give you correct `longitude` and `latitude`. in web based you will get your current `internet service provider` address rather correct location

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Location code is not working here.In fiddle it is working see link below

[Fiddle Demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/qct5j19z/)

Code below

```js
// Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
// prompted by your browser. If you see the error "The Geolocation service
// failed.", it means you probably did not give permission for the browser to
// locate you.
var map, infoWindow;
var geocoder;

function initMap() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 6
  });
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        title: 'Your position'
      });
      /*infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent('Your position');
      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);*/
      map.setCenter(pos);


      updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
      geocodePosition(pos);

      // Add dragging event listeners.
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
        updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
        updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
        updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
        updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
        geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
        map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
        updateMarkerPosition(e.latLng);
        geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
        marker.setPosition(e.latLng);
        map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
      });

    }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
  }

}

function geocodePosition(pos) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    latLng: pos
  }, function(responses) {
    if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
      updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
    } else {
      updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
    }
  });
}

function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
  document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
}

function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
    latLng.lat(),
    latLng.lng()
  ].join(', ');
}

function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
  document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
  infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
    'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
    'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
  infoWindow.open(map);
}
```

```css
#mapCanvas {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
}

#infoPanel {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#infoPanel div {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="panel">
  <!--<input id="city_country" type="textbox" value="Berlin, Germany">-->
  <input type="button" value="Locate Me" onclick="initMap()">
</div>
<div id="mapCanvas"></div>
<div id="infoPanel">
  <b>Marker status:</b>
  <div id="markerStatus"><i>Click and drag the marker.</i></div>
  <b>Current position:</b>
  <div id="info"></div>
  <b>Closest matching address:</b>
  <div id="address"></div>
</div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>
```

Comment: ist right what i am doing because the js file is in other folder and i add a #locate id for the button "working on phonegap app " https://jsfiddle.net/razanrab/qct5j19z/3/